# List of keywords --> first result URLs in Google

Tags: seo, web-crawler

Having a list of keywords (~1000), is there any out of the box tool to retrieve the first result URLs in Google for each of those keywords?

Comment: Use the Google Search API: http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Comment: Google doesn't want you to crawl its results, so you have to get creative to do that. It will block you if it detects automated requests like the ones you are describing. The API is an option, but has limited requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google API free tool is limited to 100 requests per day
You should look at SEO apps or create your own scrapping application